# How do i use MPI_Scatter()

Tags: mpi, openmp, pragma, scatter

I am trying to understand how do I call this function with regards to my program. My program is reading in a text file and putting each word into an array like so:

```
// declared outside of main
const static int ARRAY_SIZE = 130000;
using Lines = char[ARRAY_SIZE][16];

// in main
Lines lines;
int i = 0;
if (processId == 0) {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(), new letter_only())); // letter_only is defined
    file.open(argv[1]);
    std::string workString;
    while (file >> workString) {
        memset(lines[i], '\0', 16);
        memcpy(lines[i++], workString.c_str(), workString.length());
    }
}
```

I want to then divide this array up into chunks to pass to processes and then scatter the work to those processes.  I do so like this:

```
int chunk_size = i/num_processes;  // num_processes has the number of processes
int sum = 0;
int my_count = 0;
std::vector<std::string> my_string_vector;
char my_lines[chunk_size][16];

MPI_Scatter(lines,chunk_size,MPI_CHAR,my_lines,chunk_size,MPI_CHAR,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The call to MPI_Scatter causes the program to hang and I am not sure why.  Am I passing the correct values to MPI_Scatter?  is there a datatype string for MPI?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: First step: assure us that you are engaged in programming a hybrid distributed/shared memory program, and not engaged in confusing `OpenMP` and `MPI`.  If the former, almost certainly you need to explain more, if the latter, do a little research on the 'net.

Comment: do you want me to post the entire code?

Comment: No, I want you to assure us .... as I wrote in my previous comment.  If you are trying to write a hybrid MPI/OpenMP program, provide a [mcve] illustrating your question better than the snippet above.  Oh, and do it by editing your question, don't post any useful information into a new comment.

Comment: Hey I edited the original post with better information i think.